# How to get variable from json? (iam not sure with the keyword i mean)

Tags: php, arrays, json

so, here is data i get from the API. lets just call it `$eventJson`

```
{
  "to_user":"1234","event_data":[{"user_request_to":"5678", ... }],
  "users":
    {"1234"{"user_name":"john doe","user_id":"1234", ... },
    {"5678"{"user_name":"alex adam","user_id":"5678", ... }
}
```

and i cant get `to_user` id by `$eventJson->to_user;` or iam using this

```php
$my_id = $eventJson->to_user; //my id is 1234

foreach($eventJson->event_data as $item){
  $user_id = $item->user_request_to; //user id is 5678
}
```

and now how can i get the `users` data to get `user_name` from both `$my_id` or `$user_id`?

i tried with `$eventJson->$user_id->user_name;` and `$eventJson->$my_id->user_name;` but i think its wrong and its not working

Comment: Did you discover [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) yet?

Comment: Can you show your actual json? The format here is incorrect.

Comment: $eventJson = file_get_contents('php://input');
$eventJson = json_decode($eventJson);

Comment: i need to get the `user_name` but still confused how